# How can I get the days of the week in a sql statement using 2 datetimepicker in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetimepicker

I am using a 2 datetime picker where I get date from and date to, using C#.

I want to do a select statement using sql where I can list the dates from to date to just like this:

```
Ex. User selected June 1, 2013 as date from and June 15, 2013 as date to.
And this will be the result of the sql query

Date (Column name)

June 1, 2013 
June 2, 2013 
June 3, 2013
June 4, 2013 
....
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I think I got you confused guys. I don't want to know if the day is monday or tuesday. What I want to know is if it is possible for me to have a select statement where it will show all the dates from june 1, 2013 to June 15, 2013.

Comment: So you have dates stored in database and while getting value of date you want get it with Day of that data like if data saved in db is '2014-06-05' and out put will be June 6, 2014 Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you through it as there is not a direct route through the DATEPART() function:

```
DECLARE @DAY_NAME VARCHAR(10)

SELECT 
  @DAY_NAME =
      CASE (DATEPART(dw, '2014-06-01') + @@DATEFIRST) % 7
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Saturday'
  END

 SELECT @DAY_NAME
```

Cheers!